# Select all of $(this)'s selector

Tags: jquery

How do I select all items with the current selector? Might sound a bit lazy but I want to know if this is possible - and not using class name.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() {
    // Select all nodes based on this selector

    $($(this).context) // Tried this but didn't work. I want to use $(this) to get the original selector (.selector), but not use $(this).className
});
```

So instead of writing:

```
$('.selector').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

I want:

```
$($(this).getSelector()).removeClass('selected');     // Remove class from all nodes with this selector
$(this).addClass('selected');           // Only add class to the item currently clicked
```

This to not repeat the selector.

Comment: when you actually use `$(this)` then it would refer to the complete element itself. what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: What do you mean all items? Your selector is actually a class name so you'd have to get items by class name.

Comment: I want a general solution. It could be a tag or an ID as well...

Comment: In that case you need to be more specific. You can't select all elements like some other element unless you specify what's the criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now i understand your question. You should use this code:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPt5Y/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function (e) {
    $('*').css('color','black');
    var $elems = $(e.handleObj.selector);//this is what you want!
    $elems.css('color','red');
});
$(document).on('click', 'div', function (e) {
    $('*').css('color','black');
    var $elems = $(e.handleObj.selector);
    $elems.css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: the selector property was deprecated in 1.7 and removed entirely in 1.9

Comment: @jbabey Ya selector property of jquery object, not selector property of event handleObj, see works on jq2.0: http://jsfiddle.net/k4TTB

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. Then I hope they won't remove `selector` from `handleObj` like they did with jQuery objects! =)

Answer (score 4):

You have the selector hard coded, so just use it over again.

```
var selector = '.selector';
$(document).on('click', selector, function() {
    // Select all nodes based on this selector

    var matches = $(selector);
});
```

Note that there is a [`selector` property](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) on jQuery objects, but it was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9, so I do not recommend using it even if you are able.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I knew about `selector` but it doesn't work with `.on()` unfortunately. So then you can use `context`, but it only selects the item clicked...

Comment: You have event.handleObj.selector, this is what op is looking for.

Comment: @roasted `handleObj` and `selector` are undocumented and deprecated, respectively, use at your own risk :)

Comment: @jbabey Correct, cannot find any public doc on it, thx for info

Answer (score 3):

The click is done over a single element so *all* is always one. If you want to get all items matching selector you used to attach click handler you have to repeat yoursef

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() {
    var elems = $('.selector');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var selector = '.selector',
    $elems = $(selector);

$(document).on('click', selector, function() {
    // Get individual
    var $this = $(this);

    // Still can cccess all  $elems
});
```

Comment: this will only get the element that was clicked, not all elements that match the selector

Comment: closer, but this changes the behavior of the event handling from delegated to directly bound to the items